# Fetch document by array of value in MONGODB and Spring data?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How to fetch the document by array of value from MONGODB using SPRING DATA.?

My document

```
{
    "id": "5b18fdef89d67e272025f2e3",   
    "date": "2018-05-10 11:31:37",
    "active": true,
    "obsolete": false,
    "tenant": {
        "id": "5ad847e54925fb0fa4424e1a"
    },
    "plan": {
        "id": "5ad7115f7b4152204c86fce6"
    },
    "log": [
        "5b18fdef89d67e272025f2e4"
    ],
    "lineItem": [
        "5b18fdef89d67e272025f2e5",
        "5b18fdef89d67e2720259899",
        "5b18fdef89d67e272025sd5s"
    ]
}
{
        "id": "5b18fdef89d67e272025f232",   
        "date": "2018-05-12 11:31:37",
        "active": true,
        "obsolete": false,
        "tenant": {
            "id": "5ad847e54925fb0fa4424e1a"
        },
        "plan": {
            "id": "5ad7115f7b4152204c86fce6"
        },
        "log": [
            "5b18fdef89d67e272025f23434"
        ],
        "lineItem": [
            "5b18fdef89d67e272025f111",
            "5b18fdef89d67e2720259222",
            "5b18fdef89d67e272025s333"
        ]
    }
```

I want filter the document by lineItem array. If I give the lineItem value "5b18fdef89d67e2720259222" it will be return document which holds the same lineitem.

Model class

```
@Document(collection = "trn_inventory")
public class Inventory {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String date;
    private List<String> lineitem;

    private String tenant, plan;
    private List<String> log;
    private boolean active, obsolete;
    //getters and setters

}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface InventoryRep extends MongoRepository<Inventory, String> {  
    public List<Inventory> findByLineitemIn(String lineitem);
}
```

Comment: Please add here what you have tried so far?

Comment: @ClementAmarnath I have updated my question plz check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the mistake in Repository. After spend the long time, I found it myself (stupid coder). The problem is parameter of the **findByLineitemIn** method is String that should be List type.

Here is the corrected Repository...

```
@Repository
public interface InventoryRep extends MongoRepository<Inventory, String> {  
    public List<Inventory> findByLineitemIn(List<String> lineitem);
}
```

How foolish is this.. Isn't it? I think this will helpful for some other coder like me. ;)